# How to update variable proper in different struct Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-playground

In the code below, the variable "yourVariable" is defined in a struct. Then I use a slider to change the "yourVariable" but when I try and use the variable in the SecondView, it uses the original variable and not the updated one. I have been told I need to update the property, should I do this? If yes can someone please explain why.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct MyVariables {
    static var yourVariable = 500000.0
}



struct SecondView : View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var string = MyVariables.yourVariable
    var body: some View {
        VStack {Button("\(string)") {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            } 
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false

    @State public var step = 0
    @State public var text = ""
    @State public var slide = 20.0
    @State public var slidetwo = MyVariables.yourVariable + 60000
    var r0 : Double {
        rvalues[(wearingMaskToggle ? 1:0) + (washingHandsToggle ? 2:0) + (quarantineToggle ? 8:0) + (coverMouthToggle ? 4:0)]
    }
    @State private var rvalues = [6.5, 6.1, 5.3, 4.8, 4.2, 3.5, 3.1, 2.9, 1.75, 1.5, 1.2, 1.0, 0.92, 0.82, 0.75, 0.7]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            if self.slidetwo > 10000{
                                self.slidetwo -= 1000 //When rand = 10050, it still works
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "minus")
                        })
                        Slider(value: $slidetwo, in: 10000...1000000, step: 1000)
                            .padding(20)
                            .accentColor(Color.green)
                        Button(action: {
                            if self.slidetwo < 1000000{
                                self.slidetwo += 1000
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        })
                    }.foregroundColor(Color.green) .padding(.horizontal, 100)
                }
                Text("Initial Population: \(Int(slidetwo))")

                Button("Show Sheet") {
                    self.showingSheet.toggle()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                    SecondView()
                }
            }
        }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Comment: where are you changing the value of yourVariable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the slider is updating the variable `slidetwo` witch has an initial value of `560000`.

When you open the second view you are getting the value of the struct into the variable `string` witch will result in having always the value that's defined by `yourVariable`, so moving the slider does not affect at all the second view.

In order to properly do this you could use a `Binding` in case that you want the variable to be changed inside the second view and reflecting those changes in the `ContentView` or a simple un-initialized `@State var`

Going with the second option it would result in replacing, in the `SecondView` `var string = MyVariables.yourVariable` with `@State var string: String`

Then in the `ContentView` inside the sheet you call `SecondView(string: String(slidetwo))` instead of `SecondView()`

I couldn't figure out why would you need a struct in here. All it does is hold a default value and nothing more, and you don't update the variable anywhere. You can't update it directly because it can't be binded.

**Update 1:**

Based on your comment, what I understand is that you want multiple variables to the SecondView, if that's the case you are better off using and `ObservableObject` in conjunction of `EnvironmentObject`

And it's rather easy to do. First create a class that will hold all your variables. This class inherits from the `ObservableObject`

```swift
class MyVariables: ObservableObject {

    @Published var sliderTwo: Double = 0.0
    @Published var yourVariable = 500000.0 // <- I don't know the purpose of this

    init() {
        sliderTwo = yourVariable + 60000   // <- This is the original value, in the original code
    }
}
```

Now on the first view you want to initialize the class and use it where you need it. At this point the slide two will not update the `@State` variable, but the variable in the model, and we will need to pass the `ObservedObject` to the second view like so.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MyVariables = MyVariables()
    //@State public var slidetwo = MyVariables.yourVariable + 60000 <- no longer needed
    // ... change every other reference of slidertwo to model.slidertwo
    // except the following one witch instead of $slidertwo it will be $model.slidertwo
    Slider(value: $model.slidertwo, in: 10000...1000000, step: 1000)
    // ...
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
        SecondView().environmentObject(self.model) // send the model as an environment object
    }
}
```

Now we are sending the model with the data updated on the first view, to the second view, and any changes will be reflected in both views, just one last thing, capture this `EnvironmentObject` on the second view

```swift
struct SecondView: View {
    // var string = MyVariables.yourVariable <- no longer needed
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MyVariables
    // ....
}
```

In this case the `model.yourVariable` still doesn't change because we are updating the `model.slidertwo` variable.
Changes made to the model will be reflected in both views.

From the experience that I have this is the correct way to do things in SwiftUI

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that when I try and add a second variable it doesn't work, how can I fix this?

Comment: Check the updated response, basically you use a class, that inherits from `ObservableObject`, all explained

Comment: Just a note, that I did not add on my response, some times if you want only two variables you can use two `@Bindings`, you could use as many as you want but then you would get a messy code, this way you can add as many variables as you want and still keep the code clean ;)

Comment: I dont really 100% get how to implement this in my code

Comment: I can't help you more then this https://pastebin.com/gL4vh8rs and I don't like doing it, but as my response contains the exactly the same response but explained. I hope that at least you tried to understand it.
The paste that I provided is the code of the question implemented with the ObservedObject and commented out your code that's no longer necessary. Also added two buttons in the second view to watch the `ObservedObject` in action

Comment: I fixed it ans everything work but the only problem is that I cant move my slider. I did what you said but it didnt worl

Comment: Did you check the paste that I provided? That paste Is working completely in the Playground

Comment: Yes your paste in works, but for some reason mine doesnt

Comment: Can't help you more without seeing code. Maybe some thing that you forgot to change, I don't know, maybe the slider linked to the wrong variable

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PTaKbqwm there is a bit more code than the begining

Comment: A small mistake that you made, on the `ObservableObject` you don't have `@State` any variable that you want to update the UI is marked as `@Published` change `@State public var sliderone = 50000.0` to `@Published .....` and everything works just fine.

Comment: Happy to help... Another thing, but this is just for the future, in swift we use variables in camelCase witch means that for instance `sliderone` would be `sliderOne` first word always lower caps and the second word, with upper case.

Comment: Yes you can. Just use booleans `@Published var someToggle: Bool = false` if you want it to start enabled just set to true. Then in the switch just use `$model.someToggle` no braces `()`. Only classes created by yourself require more work, as long as you're using Swift's native types it all should work

Comment: I still get a "No ObservableObject of type my variable" error message...

Comment: I grabbed the code you sent via past bin previously and added a toggle to the model, and it's working fine. If you're working with the same code but with more views, make sure you always send the environment object to the other views. For instance if you're in the second view and navigate to a third view the same process applies, you just don't create a new `@ObservedObject` just pass the current `@EnvironmentObject`

Comment: Im still working with the same view... Do you mind sharing the code?

Comment: Can you show a small portion of the code, where you're getting the error

Comment: Toggle(isOn: $modal.washingHandsToggle) {
                        Text("Washing Hands Regularly")
                    }.padding(.horizontal, 50.0)
                        .padding(.vertical, 15)

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong there the problem must be in the model. If every other reference to that model works, if so it must be the variable, that's not defined properly

Comment: If you have any time to look over my code that would help so much. What I want to do is create the variable washingHandsToggle and use the value in my contentview in my secondview, thanks. https://pastebin.com/7dCaRGUm

Comment: You were not initializing the `@ObservedObject` but rather waiting for an `@EnvironmentObject` witch was never passed from the previous view. I changed it to `@ObservedObject` and initialized the object and it seems to work, I commented the changes that I did to help you understand.
You could also leave `@EnvironmentObject` in the `ContentView` but that would require you to change the last line of the playground to: `PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView()).environmentObject(MyVariables())`
Here's the updated code https://pastebin.com/gL4vh8rs, check lines 66, 87, 94,102 - 106

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I'm too late but what you could also adjust in your code is to change the slideTwo variable to.

```
@Binding public var slidetwo: Double
```

You'd have to do the +60000 addition in the struct directly and then initialize your view as follows:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView(slidetwo: .init(get: { () -> Double in
    return MyVariables.yourVariable
}, set: { (newValue) in
    MyVariables.yourVariable = newValue
})))
```

That would result in applying all changes to `slideTwo` to be applied to `yourVariable` as well. However, as Pedro already mentioned, I wouldn't recommend that approach with the struct.

Comment: where do I put the @Binding? and how many variables can I use?

Comment: @EliasFizesan instead of `@State public var slidetwo = MyVariables.yourVariable + 60000`. But don't forget to initialize `static var yourVariable` with `560000.0` instead of `500000.0`. The @Binding annotation allows you to "sync back" your changes to `slideTwo`, that means whenever you change this value, your `MyVariables.yourVariable` will also be updated due to the getter/setter I provided in the second code snippet of my answer.

Comment: I don't understand your question _"and how many variables can I use?"_. You can you as many variables as you want.